# change description under email field on user registration form

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have created sub-domain for English and Spanish, that is why I used [Multilingual](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module in Spanish to use Spanish language in my website. There is description under email address field does not change. I also add my Spanish description in drupal-7.32.es.po file but does not have effect.

```
 msgid "A valid e-mail address is required. All e-mails from the system will be sent to this address. The e-mail address is not made public and will only be used if you want to receive a new password or wish to receive certain news or notifications by e-mail."
 msgstr "Se requiere una dirección válida de correo electrónico. Todos los correos del sistema serán enviados a esta dirección. La dirección de correo electronico no se hará pública y solo sera utilizada si usted solicita una nueva contraseña o desea recibir ciertas notificias y notificaciones por esta vía."
```

This msgid description is same as in user.module, I also enable field translation but nothing happend. How i can do this changes in my spanish site.